# How to add an extender to each observable in knockout viewmodel?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

i'm trying to add an extender to all my observables in my viewmodel. my data come from the server so i can't specify the properties one by one.

i tried this but it doens't work, i'm using the logChange extender from the knockout js webpage for this example.

```
var addingExtender = {
  key: function (data) {
        return data.id;
    },
  create: function(options) {
            return ko.observable(true).extend({ logChange: "Value Changed" });

    }
};
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, addingExtender, self);
```

Comment: Look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325352

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing a function to add the extender one by one.

```
function addStorage(koViewModel,name) {
    for (var observableKey in koViewModel) {
        if (ko.isObservable(koViewModel[observableKey]) 
        && !isObservableArray(koViewModel[observableKey])) {

            koViewModel[observableKey].extend({ persist: name === undefined ?
                   url + observableKey : url + name +     "." + observableKey });
        }

        if (typeof koViewModel[observableKey] === "object") {
            for (var observables in koViewModel[observableKey]) {
                if (ko.isObservable(koViewModel[observableKey][observables]) 
                && !isObservableArray(koViewModel[observableKey][observables])) {

                    koViewModel[observableKey][observables].extend({ persist: url +
                           observableKey + "." + observables });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Typescript Syntax, **Recursively extending leaf observables**

```
extendObservables(vm: object): void {
    for (var observableKey in vm) {
        if (!vm.hasOwnProperty(observableKey) || observableKey == "__ko_mapping__") {
            continue;
        }

        if (ko.isObservable(vm[observableKey]) && typeof ko.unwrap(vm[observableKey]) === "object") {
            this.extendObservables(ko.unwrap(vm[observableKey]));
        } else if (ko.isObservable(vm[observableKey])) {
            extendObservable(vm[observableKey]);
        } else if (typeof vm[observableKey] === "object") {
            this.extendObservables(vm[observableKey]);
        }
    }
}
```